# Can i open the linked object to another blender session from current scene?

Tags: linked-data

I imported (link) another .blend files into my scene. To view those link paths, in outliner , i change the display mode to 'blender file'. There's a path list there, but :

1. how do i know which one is which? If i select any object (the linked object), there's no indication in the outliner to show which blend path it is.
2. How can i select the linked object and open it in other blender session ? so i can modify/edit the master file. I don't want to append. I want to edit the source without manually find it in explorer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. There's cool builtin addon : **edit linked library**.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/addons/object/edit_linked_library.html

I simply click the button on the side bar and it will take me to the linked .blend file , edit it and use the sidebar again to go back to previous blend file.